# An orbit of a group action and the implicit function theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, banach-spaces, vector-bundles, group-actions

Suppose that a Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a manifold $X$. We can easily prove the following theorem by using [the constant rank theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_rank_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem), which is a stronger theorem than the implicit function theorem.

> **Theorem A**. Let $x$ be a point of $X$ and define $F:G \to X$ by $F(g)=gx$. Then
>   there are open neighbourhoods $U \subset G$ of the identity and
>   $V \subset X$ of $x$ such that $F(U)$ is a closed submanifold of $V$.

Questions:

(i) Is it possible to prove Theorem A by using the implicit function theorem (without applying the constant rank theorem)?

(ii) [Atiyah-Bott](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1983.0017) use an infinite-dimensional version of Theorem A in §14: Fix a complex (smooth) vector bundle $E$ over a closed Riemann surface $M$ with a Hermitian metric. Let $G$ be the group $(\mathcal{G}^c)^k$ of complex gauge transformations of class $L^2_k$ and $X$ the space $\mathcal{A}^{k-1}$ of unitary connections of class $L^2_{k-1}$ ($k \geq 2$). According to Atiyah-Bott, we can prove Theorem A in this case by using the implicit function theorem for Banach manifolds. (We may need the Fredholm property of the derivative $dF$.)

How do we prove Theorem A in this case?

(iii) Do we have an infinite-dimensional version of the constant rank theorem (which can be applied to Question (ii))?

Comment: for $iii)$, I hope you get more answers than http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377157/infinite-dimensional-constant-rank-theorem

Comment: So far I can not find any helpful discussion in the book by Lang.

Comment: I think there is an infinite dimensional version of the constant rank theorem, under assumption of the existence of suitable topological "supplementaries" (unsure of the english terminology, sorry ; it's related to what you say about the Fredholm property). it is not mentionned in Lang's book, but I believe the proof of the classical constant rank theorem can be carried just the same (it uses the immersion and submersion lemmas for Banach spaces, which are proved in Lang). I have not thought about how to apply it to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer to your third question:

There are versions of the constant rank theorem which could be applicable to your situation:

Some versions of the constant rank theorem between Banach spaces can be found in

Margalef-Roig, J. and E. Outerelo Dominguez, “Differential Topology,”
North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1992.

Also a version of the constant rank theorem is contained as Theorem F in 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05795.pdf